# Switching monitor/tv display modes for Windows

Tags: scripting, windows-8

I have 2 DELL monitors and a tv. I frequently use my tv to stream movies. I'd like to create a script so that my secondary screen switches from my secondary DELL monitor to the tv without affecting my primary monitor.

I know this can be achieved by various means, but I'd like to create a script so that it will be able to detect the current active screen and then switch to the other so that my wife can just double click on it to switch between the two.

Can someone help me get started by letting me know which scripting language I can use and which libraries/dlls I will need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's curious I ended up creating a C# console application for this. This way I could use the WinAPIs to determine what display mode I was in and switch to the one that I wanted. It won't be setup for how everyone will want it but it should be a good starting point.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DisplaySwitcher
{
    class Program
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);

        public const int SM_CMONITORS = 80;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int iNumberOfDisplays = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS);
            string displaySwitch = null;
            switch (iNumberOfDisplays)
            {
                case 1: // TV mode (only detects 1 display)
                    displaySwitch += "/external";
                    break;
                case 2: // Normal mode (extended display)
                    displaySwitch += "/clone";
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Unknown display mode detected");
                    break;
            }

            executeCommand(displaySwitch);
        }

        private static void executeCommand(string displaySwitch)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "DisplaySwitch.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = displaySwitch;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
        }

    }
}
```